# Why parallel testing in not available by default in Xcode 10?

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, testing

I wonder if Xcode 10 has such nice feature as parallel testing why it is off by default?
If there any cases when I would better use this feature turned off for my testing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your test cases interact with one another in any way, then running them in parallel will cause intermittent failures. A very common example is if unit tests work with a database and each test does not create a unique database. It is very common for developers to fail to carefully consider test interactions, and many existing test suites would certainly fail if you ran them in parallel.

Comment: Thank you, Rob ! So and I should not use randomise on my tests if I use it for DataBase tests?

Comment: You shouldn't if the tests interact with each other. If you are careful, you can certainly run database tests in parallel, and ideally tests should not interact with each other. There is a very good argument that you *should* run them in parallel and random order specifically to find places they interact so you can fix them. But…having done this, it can be a major investment and you can spend substantial time debugging tests rather than shipping code. Finding the right balance is a challenge. If I were a beginner w/ a small code base, I personally wouldn't use parallel tests at all.

Comment: Thank you for so great explanation!

Comment: Parallel is a bad idea if your codebase is using lots of `static` properties. Learned it the hard way